# How to add 3 images at the left bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add 3 images of social medias at the left bottom of the page so the effect might looks like this:

[image]

And how it looks now (I have got 3 really big images despite setting the width and height):

[image]

I am wondering what I am doing wrong. These 3 images are in the social folder.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DingDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id ="logo"> <img src="dingdog-logo.png"> </ul>

      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li ><a href="">NEWS FEED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT DINGDOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="">AUTHORS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li id ="sign"><a href="">SIGN IN</a></li>
      </ul>

  </header>
  <div class="sociale">
    <img src="social/instagramOficial.png" />
    <img src="social/twitter.png" />
    <img src="social/facebook.png" />
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header
{
  background: #949e9b 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  width: auto;
  height: 78px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("dog.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.main-nav
{
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Bold 20px/12px Arial;
  padding: 5px;
}

#logo
{
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
}

#sign a
{
  background-color: #DCDFDE;
  padding: 30px 15px 23px 15px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.sociale
{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make the children of the social block inline-block

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header
{
  background: #949e9b 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  width: auto;
  height: 78px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("dog.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.main-nav
{
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.main-nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a
{
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: Bold 20px/12px Arial;
  padding: 5px;
}

#logo
{
  margin-top: 5px;
  float: left;
}

#sign a
{
  background-color: #DCDFDE;
  padding: 30px 15px 23px 15px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.sociale
{
  display: block;
}
.social > img
{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>DingDog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id ="logo"> <img src="dingdog-logo.png"> </ul>

      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li ><a href="">NEWS FEED</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT DINGDOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="">AUTHORS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li id ="sign"><a href="">SIGN IN</a></li>
      </ul>

  </header>
  <div class="sociale">
    <img src="social/instagramOficial.png" />
    <img src="social/twitter.png" />
    <img src="social/facebook.png" />
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you want to have it always at the bottom of the page you have to change it to:

```
.sociale {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}

.social>img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to inherit? Why it does not work like I did?